# Are isomorphic maximal tori stably conjugate?

Tags: group-cohomology, reductive-groups, root-systems, counterexamples, conjugacy-classes

Let $F$ be a field and $G$ a reductive $F$-group. For various applications it is important to understand the "classes" of maximal ($F$-)tori of $G$. Here "class" can mean the following, in decreasing order of strength:

- rational conjugacy, i.e., $G(F)$-conjugacy
- stable conjugacy, i.e., $G(\overline F)$-conjugacy where $\overline F$ is the separable closure of $F$
- isomorphism (of $F$-tori)

In $\text{GL}_n$ these equivalence relations coincide. In general, it is well-known that rational conjugacy is stronger than stable conjugacy. My question is about comparing stably conjugacy and isomorphism.

> **Question 1:** If two maximal tori are isomorphic (as $F$-tori) then are they stably conjugate?
> In other words, can isomorphic maximal tori fail to be stably conjugate?

I'm especially interested in the case where $F$ is a finite, local, or global field, but I'm happy to hear about other cases too.

I would be surprised if the answer were "yes" because then presumably people would speak of isomorphism classes instead of stable conjugacy classes, as the former is a simpler notion. On the other hand, I have not been able to find an example of isomorphic but non-stably-conjugate maximal tori.

**Reformulation:** Here is a different way of formulating the question. Suppose $G$ is quasi-split and $T$ is a fixed maximal torus (if you like, a minimal Levi subgroup). Then by Raghunathan's theorem, the stable conjugacy classes of maximal tori of $G$ are classified by the Galois cohomology set $H^1(F,W)$ where $W=W(G,T)$ is the Weyl group. On the other hand, by general facts about Galois descent, the isomorphism classes of $F$-tori are classified by the cohomology set $H^1(F,\text{Aut}(T)) = H^1(F,\text{GL}(X^*(T)))$ where $X^*(T)$ is the character lattice of $T$.

> **Question 2:** Is the map $H^1(F,W)\to H^1(F,\text{Aut}(T))$ injective?

**Special case**: When $F=\mathbb{F}_q$ and $G$ is split, the $H^1$'s become sets of conjugacy classes and the question becomes whether the map
$$
W/\!/W \to \text{Aut}(T)_\text{fin}/\!/\text{Aut}(T)
$$
is injective, where $/\!/$ denotes conjugacy classes and $\text{Aut}(T)_\text{fin}$ is the subset of finite-order elements. In general, conjugacy classes change on passage to a larger group, so injectivity would require some special property of the situation.
One place to look for a counterexample is the map
$$
W/\!/W \to \text{Aut}(\Phi)/\!/\text{Aut}(\Phi)
$$
where $\Phi=\Phi(G,T)$ is the root system; if this map is not injective then the map above will also not be injective. But I played around with several examples, including $D_4$ in GAP, and this map seems to be injective.

**Update:** Loren Spice pointed out that there are obvious examples if $G$ is not almost-simple, just by taking $G = H \times H$, $T_1$ and $T_2$ in $H$ non-isomorphic, and $T=T_1\times T_2$ and $T'=T_2\times T_1$ in $G$; then $T$ and $T'$ are isomorphic but not stably conjugate, though they are conjugate by an outer automorphism of $G$. So let's focus on the case where $G$ is almost simple.

Comment: The paper "On Conjugacy Classes of Maximal Tori in Classical Groups" by Kazutoshi Kariyama (J. Algebra 125(1989), no.1, 133–149) is a very relevant reference. I think one can construct a counterexample in $\operatorname{SL}_n$ or $\operatorname{Sp}_{2n}$ from their main results by doing some class field theory.

Comment: Thanks Pol, very interesting paper! I don't see how there could be a counterexample for $\text{SL}_n$ though because isn't stable conjugacy there the same as in $\text{GL}_n$?

Comment: I think it might be natural to look for classical counterexamples using that conjugacy class in $\mathsf D_{2n}$ that's not determined by its cycle type.

Comment: I suspected that type $D$ could be a good place to look. Do you happen to know a description of this conjugacy class?

Comment: [Re](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1213166), I should have said "those conjugacy classes"; every cycle type with all cycles even and positive splits into two $\mathsf D_n$ conjugacy classes.  (This is Proposition 25 of [Carter - Conjugacy classes in the Weyl group](http://www.numdam.org/item/CM_1972__25_1_1_0).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\DeclareMathOperator\GL{GL}\DeclareMathOperator\SL{SL}\DeclareMathOperator\PGL{PGL}\DeclareMathOperator\Gal{Gal}$Let $(B, S)$ be a Borel–torus pair in $G \mathrel{:=} \mathsf G_2$, let $\alpha_1$ be the short, and $\alpha_2$ the long, simple root in $\mathsf G_2$, and let $M_i$ be the centraliser of $\alpha_i^\vee$.  Then the intersection with $S$ of the derived subgroup of $M_i$ is the image of the positive coroot, which is the fundamental coweight $\varpi_{3 - i}^\vee$; the central torus in $M_i$ is the image of $\alpha_i^\vee$; and $\mathbb Z\varpi_{3 - i}^\vee + \mathbb Z\alpha_i^\vee$ has index $2$ in $X_*(S)$.  It follows that $M_i$ is $\GL_2$.

If $E/F$ is a quadratic, Galois extension and $T_i$ is the non-split torus in $M_i \cong \GL_2$ that splits over $E$, then $T_1$ is isomorphic to $T_2$; but the cocycle corresponding to $T_1$ sends the non-trivial element of $\Gal(E/F)$ to the conjugacy class $\mathsf A_1$, and the cocycle corresponding to $T_2$ sends it to the conjugacy class $\tilde{\mathsf A}_1$, in the labelling of [Carter - Conjugacy classes in Weyl groups](http://www.numdam.org/item/CM_1972__25_1_1_0), p. 31.  By Lemma 26 of that reference, $\mathsf A_1$ and $\tilde{\mathsf A}_1$ are different conjugacy classes, so $T_1$ and $T_2$ are not stably conjugate.

Comment: Very nice example Loren! More generally, this works for any non-simply-laced root system, basically because the Weyl group can distinguish root lengths but the general linear group cannot. I wonder though, if there are any examples in simply-laced groups.

Comment: It would also be very interesting to find an example where the tori are elliptic.

Comment: @DavidSchwein, I'm not 100% sure it works for every non-simply laced root system; for example, for Sp_4, one of the Levis is GL_2, and the other is SL_2 x GL_1.  I don't think the non-split tori in GL_2 embed in SL_2 x GL_1.

Comment: Ah, ok, good point: the tori I had in mind are isogenous but not isomorphic. In fact, since $\text{Sp}_4$ embeds in all the other non-simply laced almost-simple groups besides $G_2$, it seems like maybe this long root/short root idea only works in $G_2$. Hm.